# Heat transfer on Mars

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, planets, convection, radiative-transfer

SCENARIO:

I have been tasked with finding the heat transfer across a composite wall on Mars.

On the left of the wall there is air maintained at Earth atmospheric conditions and room temperature (101 KPa, $21^\circ  C$). On the right there is Martian air, residing at approximately 1 Kpa and $0^\circ C$ perhaps with a light breeze of 4 m/s.

The diving wall is made up of an internal sheet of aluminium, 5cm thick, and a slab of Martian soil 50cm thick.

QUESTION:

From left to right, heat enters the wall through convection + radiation, travels through the wall via conduction, and leaves the wall through conduction and radiation. I believe if I can compute R values for each of these, I can combine them in parallel and series to find an overall R coefficient in order to find the power required to maintain the temperature at 21 C.

**My struggle is to find the correct R values for convection and radiation, most importantly because I do not know how to find the convective heat transfer coefficients. I have looked through literature but not found anything useful. Any advice?**

Comment: How are you going to calculate the R value of the Martian soil? What terrestrial analog are you going to use?

Comment: At such low temperatures you can neglect radiative losses.

Comment: This should be of interest: http://fc.civil.tamu.edu/resources/en/engr214/chapter7/node13.html

Comment: @Rick Various sources are available which estimate the thermal conductivity of Martian soil (this is one example https://www.researchgate.net/publication/223478499_Theoretical_prediction_of_the_thermal_conductivity_and_temperature_variation_inside_Mars_soil_analogues) which estimates a k value of 0.144 W/mk, leading to an R value of R = t/k = 0.5/0.144

Comment: @Gert thanks for the link that is very useful. If I was to include radiation would I simply add it in as one of the boundary conditions mentioned in that paper? i.e. instead of conduction = convection, we have conduction = convection + radiation.

Some sources I have read have stated that radiation on Mars would be quite significant compared to convection due to the atmosphere and low temp compared to the temp of the wall

Comment: No. Take the outer temperature of the wall and the temperature of the Martian atmosphere, then apply Stefan-Boltzmann: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law. Not difficult.

Comment: @Gert by applying Stefan-Boltzmann and including radiation, does that not mean that Conduction = Convection at the surface though? This was the assumed boundary condition, but now some heat that has passed through the wall via conduction is now leaving as radiation rather than convection

Comment: *"[...] does that not mean that Conduction = Convection at the surface though?"* I see where you're coming from but 'No, not at all'. You simply sum the two terms: convection + radiation. I'll see if I can find and example of it.

Comment: An example of the heat equation with convection and radiation: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/151209/heat-equation-with-heat-radiation-and-heat-transfer. Note how the convection and radiative terms simply add together.